# Windows 10 VPN Connect Button Cumbersome

Tags: vpn, windows-10, user-interface

I installed Win 10 Pro and added a Windows VPN connection.

When I press the network icon in lower right edge, I see all my connections including my VPN connection.

However, when I click on it, the settings app opens and only then can I click "Connect."

That's so cumbersome! Is there any way to make the connect/disconnect button show up with my list of networks like so:

[image: http://strongvpn.com/img/setup/win10/pptp/11.jpg]

Comment: I'm having this exact annoyance @rene_r, I want my old connect button back!

Comment: Open regedit (WIN+R and type regedit.exe)
Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Control Panel\Settings\Network
Take ownership of the “Network” key/folder (right click, Permissions)
Select “Advanced” in the Permissions window
In the Advanced window, select “Change” where the owner field is (top of the window)
Type in your username and save your changes.
Close the advanced window.
Now select “Administrators” in the security tab.
Make sure “Full control” is selected, then apply changes. 
Now that’s done, double click “ReplaceVan”
Change it’s value to 2

Answer (score 16):

I'm amazed that the Windows experience seems to be moving further and further away from what is surely one of the most fundamental aspects of computing: the ability to launch a program or sequence with a single action.

For sure, Windows 10 is like a breath of fresh air after Windows 8, but it has some awful characteristics.

Requiring us to go through a whole series of clicks, dialogs and selections simply to connect our VPN is not my idea of progress. This is not the way I want to use Windows. But I'm less and less able to use to use Windows my way under today's Windows experience, forced more and more to do things in cumbersome ways.

*Affiliation disclosure per our [site etiquette](https://superuser.com/help/promotion): this answer involves freeware I wrote.*

Frustrated by the Windows VPN UI, I recently wrote a little app that sits in the system tray and manages the VPN *my* way:

[image: VPNMyWay]

If this sounds like your way to use a Windows VPN... [enjoy!](https://vpnmyway.wordpress.com/)

Comment: Thanks man! It works great! My exchange rate is terrible - but have a beer on me!

Comment: Handy app, nice work. Is there any way to use this for multiple VPN connections? Also, an easy way to make changes would be helpful as well. I appreciate the time you put into this, thank you.

Comment: @WindowsNinja yes you can use multiple VPN connections--see the [FAQ](https://vpnmyway.wordpress.com/faq/) for details and an example.

Comment: I've been looking over the directions on the FAQ and they don't seem to provide a clear path to putting this in place. Would you be willing to try and add some clarity there?

Comment: This worked great for me as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: here's a way to do return old way without extra software
https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3fawdy/connect_to_vpn_from_task_bar/

Comment: @IgorBe Please consider adding that comment as an actual answer; I think it may be exactly what many people are looking for in this question.

Answer (score 5):

The best way I can find (this is a really old trick) is to create a new shortcut to "c:\windows\system32\rasdial.exe (your vpn connection name)".  The bummer is that you'll either need to go thru the same extra clicks above to end the connection or create a second shortcut with the /DISCONNECT switch.

[More here at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614465/establish-a-vpn-connection-in-cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614465/establish-a-vpn-connection-in-cmd)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.