# Is there any way to fix an annoying Windows 10 UI design re: VPN connections?

Tags: vpn, windows-10

For as long as I can remember (definitely as far back as Vista, possibly XP as well) to connect to a VPN connection in Windows I could just click on the network icon in taskbar, select the VPN connection, and click "Connect".

However, with Windows 10 when you click on the VPN connection it now opens a new control panel window where you then have to select the VPN connection again and then click "Connect".

This is very annoying and adds additional windows and clicks simply for no god reason.

Does anybody know if this can be reverted to the old way where I can connect from directly within the taskbar icon?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 10 RTM - VPN - Connection - Connect Button](http://superuser.com/questions/947060/windows-10-rtm-vpn-connection-connect-button)

Comment: Seems to be, yes. Although there was no solution to that question.